# Selection Criteria when running an SP

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvLrc.png)So I created a small SP which is working fine, however I would like to be able to make it ask you to select a start and end date when executing it, thus far I have had no joy in working it out.

Below is my query, could someone please advise me what I need to do in order to force you to select both the start and end date when executing?

I have tried a hundred different @set date commands but am not winning (I am not a pro at this but leaning as I go along).

also attached is a screenshot of what I see when executing the SP, there is nothing parameters which is what I am struggling with.

Thanks!

```
USE [CBS_AFRICA_LIVECOPY]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_LOADINGHOURS]    Script Date: 25/01/2019 19:54:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_LOADINGHOURS]
AS

SELECT FOLIO_NUMBER, STATUS,  FORMAT(TERM_START_LOAD_TIME ,'HH') as TERM_START_LOAD_TIME, FORMAT(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME ,'HH')
as TERM_END_LOAD_TIME,TERMINAL_NAME, TERMINAL_ID FROM ORDERS 

JOIN TERMINAL_OWNER ON ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = TERMINAL_OWNER.TERMINAL_ID

ORDER BY FOLIO_NUMBER DESC
```

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/   first result that came up when I googled.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_LOADINGHOURS] 
@startdate as datetime,
@enddate as datetime

AS
Begin

SELECT FOLIO_NUMBER, STATUS,  
FORMAT(TERM_START_LOAD_TIME ,'HH') as 
TERM_START_LOAD_TIME, 
FORMAT(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME ,'HH') as 
TERM_END_LOAD_TIME,
TERMINAL_NAME, 
TERMINAL_ID 
FROM ORDER JOIN TERMINAL_OWNER ON 
ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = 
TERMINAL_OWNER.TERMINAL_ID

Where DBTABLE.DATE>=@startdate 
AND    DBTABLE.DATE<=@enddate

ORDER BY FOLIO_NUMBER DESC

End
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!!  It is working the way I want it.  Great forum this.